# Verifying Haar Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, haar-measure

I am reading Haar Measure right now.
Definition: For G be locally compact Hausdorff group. A left Haar functional on G is a non trivial positive linear functional on $C_{c}(G)$ which is invariant under left translation.
I am reading an example of G=$\mathbb{R^{*}}$.
The map $D$ from $C_{c}(G)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f \mapsto \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\frac{dx}{|x|}$ is left and right Haar functional. It can be verified using classical substitution principle. In last it concluded that D defines a left and right Haar measure on G.
I don’t know how this concluded. I have read a theorem that for every Haar functional on G we have a Haar measure in G and conversely. Having some hint or suggestion would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any Borel set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^*$ we can define $$\mu (A) = \int_A \frac{1}{|x|} dx$$ where $dx$ stands for integration against the Lebesgue measure. This measure is Borel regular and locally finite; as advertised, you can argue by change of variables to show that this measure is translation invariant.

You may conclude that this is indeed a Haar measure. Notice that since $\mathbb{R}^*$ is an Abelian group this measure is, at once, the left and right Haar measure for this group.

Comment: Dear Jose, How to verify its Regular and locally finite?

Comment: $\mu$ is locally finite because $\frac{1}{|x|}$ is bounded on compact sets. Since $\mathbb{R}^*$ is second countable, regularity follows (see Folland Real Analysis Thm 7.8).